# Which tie break system would be used in Tata Steel 2015?

Tags: tournament

Which tie break system would be used in Tata Steel 2015?

I didn't find it on the tournament website. I don't know how to get it.

Comment: There is an old tiebreak listed under http://www.tatasteelchess.com/news/view/id/585/c/Tiebreak_Corus_Chess_Tournament 
1. Result in direct matchup
2. Sonneborn Berger-Points
3. Most games as black
4. Drawing 
However it is doubtful this system is still in effect, because Wikipedia claims, that they used Sonneborn-Berger as first tie break the last few years.

Comment: It astonishes me how difficult it regularly is to find information about the tiebreak procedure in major tournaments. Often the live commentators are reduced to wild speculation because no one knows what the tiebreak system actually is.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if there is no fact no tiebreaker system, and joint winners are just joint winners. But can't find any regulations either.

Comment: Sistema de desempate: (http://www.ajedrez21.com/blog/tata15/). 
Puntos.
Encuentro directo.
SonnebornBerger.
Nº partidas con negras.
Elo.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this question is still relevant … :)

I have looked up this information on [chess24.com's broadcast page](https://chess24.com/en/watch/live-tournaments/tataSteelMasters2015/13/1/1) for that event. They are usually in direct contact to the organizers and their *Information* tab is relatively reliable.

According to that page the tiebreak rules were as follows:

1. Points scored
2. Direct encounter
3. [Sonneborn-Berger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonneborn%E2%80%93Berger_score)
4. Most games played with Black
5. Rating

Keep in mind this is from a secondary source. If you want to be sure, ask the organizers.

Comment: Good to know! I'm looking forward to follow this tournament having all the rules in mind in case of a close race.